# Ler arquivo txt

Tags: angularjs, txt

Estou criando uma aplicação WEB e preciso ler um arquivo txt que será fornecido pelo usuário. O código que estou utilizando para realizar a leitura não está dando certo e não consigo encontrar em outros lugares um jeito de fazer a leitura.

```js
// Código dentro do controller
$scope.imprimir = function () {
  lerArquivoTxt.carregarArquivo();
}

// Código dentro do service
function _carregarArquivoTxt() {
  var arquivoSelecionado = document.getElementById('arquivoPastas');
  var divSaida = document.getElementById('textoLido');
  var fileExtension = /text.*/;
  var arquivoLeitura = arquivoSelecionado.files[0];
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsText(arquivoLeitura);
  divSaida.innerText = 'resultado: ' + fileReader.result;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group" id="arquivo">
<div class="lbltitulo" for="Numero">Selecione o arquivo base para criar as pastas do projeto:</div>
<div class="tbpdd16">
  <input  type="file" 
          id="arquivoPastas"
          class="hideBtn btn btn-warning">
</div>

<div class="">
  <input  type="text" 
          id="txtfiletoread" 
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Pasta / sub pasta"
          ng-model="pasta.pasta">
</div>
<div id="textoLido"></div>
```

A idéia é que o usuário selecione um arquivo por meio do input file, o controller chama a função _carregarArquivoTxt() do service e esta função ler e retornar todo o arquivo lido.
Preciso de ajuda com o código que faz a leitura do arquivo txt.

Comment: Tem como colocar todo o código! principalmente do Angular

Comment: Você viu o exemplo e ai serviu pra você?

Comment: Ainda não tive tempo de testar a solução proposta.

Comment: Ok !!! Thiago ...

Comment: Virgilio Novic, o código que vc postou funciona, se eu criar um novo projeto e adicionar o código lê o arquivo e atribui o texto lido dentro da div perfeitamente. No entanto, aplicar esse código ao projeto que estou criando não funciona. O que eu gostaria que fazer é chamar essa função de leitura do arquivo através do service, atribuir o conteúdo lido a uma variável para então trabalhar com essa variável e depois mostrar o conteúdo lido numa table.

Comment: O problema de trabalhar no service ou qualquer parte do seu código é um fator chamado no mundo da informática adaptação, você tem um exemplo funcional do código, você não postou o seu código angular completo apenas trecho, é quer uma resposta para uma solução que nós não conhecemos como já foi dito, pela falta de código, Quer uma código pronto para a sua solução, poste o seu código angular na integra e aponte o local que deseja que funcione e como quer que funcione, ou seja, a [edite a sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/230967/edit) e coloque como deveria ser.

Comment: ... conti: vale lembrar também que a `directive` criada atualiza o `$scope.text` que é um objeto com o campo `value` que pode e deve ser utilizado da melhor forma possivel. Foi feito assim pela lógica de selecionado o arquivo `.txt` e logo de cara mostrar o resultado, mas, reafirmando falta dados na sua pergunta e [a edição seria a melhor forma de apontar como seria a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/230967/edit).

Comment: Consegui fazer o código funcionar, o problema era que eu estava atribuindo o reader.result a um vetor, e não a um objeto como vc mostrou no código.

Comment: Ok isso é bom quando se consegue resolver, se a resposta te serviu aceite ela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para carregar o texto de um arquivo `.txt` com [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) crie uma diretiva que no momento da alteração do `input file` vai mostrar o conteudo texto em uma `div`, ***exemplo***:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.text = {
    value: 'Esperando ...'
  };  
});
app.directive("fileTxt", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(reader) {
          return function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.text.value = reader.result;            
            });        
            return reader.result;
          }
        })(reader);
        reader.readAsText(elem[0].files[0]);
      });      
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="file" file-txt ng-model="fileItem" name="fileTxt">
  <br />
  <br />
  <div>{{text.value}}</div>  
  
</div>
```

Não esqueça de colocar no seu `input file` a diretiva `file-txt` da seguinte forma:

```
 <input type="file" file-txt ng-model="fileItem" name="fileTxt">
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Read text file using FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371970/read-text-file-using-filereader)
- [$apply()](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html)
- [Is there a way to bind to a model from a parent scope without passing it to a directive’s isolate scope as an attribute? - <sup>SOEn</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719199/is-there-a-way-to-bind-to-a-model-from-a-parent-scope-without-passing-it-to-a-di)
- [Creating Custom AngularJS Directives Part 2 – Isolate Scope](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope)
- [Template-expanding directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- [Directive to get files input with ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064288/directive-to-get-files-input-with-ng-model)
- [angular - input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)